# Converting a CSV to dictionary then looking it up via map() function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataframe called DummyData

```
    Cover   Age Are   AddFlag
0   COMP    33  4     1
1   COMP    67  47    1
2   COMP    17  155   1
3   COMP    24  35    1
4   COMP    66  57    1
```

My second data frame is called BaseRate

```
    Cover   Anchor
0   COMP    1000.0
1   TPFT    850.0
2   TPO     840.0
```

I run the following code:

```
BaseRate = BaseRate.set_index(['Cover'])
CoverDict = BaseRate.to_dict()
print(CoverDict)
```

and it returns

```
{'Anchor': {'COMP': 1000.0, 'TPFT': 850.0, 'TPO': 840.0}}
```

I then run

```
DummyData["Anchor"] = DummyData["Cover"].map(Anchor)
DummyData.head()
```

but I get

> NameError: name 'Anchor' is not defined.

What I want is DummyData to have the Anchor variable appended to it (like a vlookup in Excel)

```
        Cover   Age Area    AddFlag Base    Anchor
0   COMP    33  4   1   1000.0  1000.0
1   COMP    67  47  1   1000.0  1000.0
2   COMP    17  155 1   1000.0  1000.0
3   COMP    24  35  1   1000.0  1000.0
4   COMP    66  57  1   1000.0  1000.0
```

If I run

```
Anchor = {'COMP': 1000.0, 'TPFT': 850.0, 'TPO': 840.0}
```

then my code works. I wanty to lose the curly brackets

Any help appreciated as I'm new to Python. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`"Anchor"` is a key in your `CoverDict` pointing to the map you want to use.

You can access it like this:

```
DummyData["Anchor"] = DummyData["Cover"].map(CoverDict["Anchor"])
```

In your code, you tried to access a variable called `Anchor` when you did `.map(Anchor)`, buy you would have to define that variable before using it.

You could also have defined it like this and then kept your call:

```
Anchor = CoverDict["Anchor"]
DummyData["Anchor"] = DummyData["Cover"].map(Anchor)
```